# Memory leak char* C program

Tags: c, string, char, malloc

Let's look at the following piece of C code used to copy a string of undefined length into a structure:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct nNameStruct{
  char* nName;
  //char* nName2;
} nNameStruct;

nNameStruct * NameCreate(char *buffer) {
  nNameStruct *pNew;
  pNew = (nNameStruct*) malloc(sizeof(nNameStruct*));
  pNew->nName = (char*) malloc((strlen(buffer)+1)*sizeof(char*));
  strcpy(pNew->nName,buffer);
  //pNew->nName2 = (char*) malloc((strlen(buffer)+1)*sizeof(char*));
  //strcpy(pNew->nName2,buffer);
  return pNew;
}

int main() {
  nNameStruct *newName;
  char buffer[]="Trial string";

  newName=NameCreate(buffer);
  printf("%s\n",newName->nName);
  //printf("%s\n",newName->nName2);

  free(newName->nName);
  //free(newName->nName2);
  free(newName);
  return 0;
}
```

This program runs quite fine. However if I want to allocate also another string (using the commented lines) I have memory leak problems and valgrind check is full of errors. What's the problem here?

Comment: You call `malloc(sizeof(nNameStruct*))` is wrong. It will allocate bytes for a *pointer* to `nNameStruct`. You want `sizeof(nNameStruct)`.

Comment: Your `sizeof()` in `malloc()` are wrong you want the size of the object not the pointer so `sizeof(nNameStruct)` and `sizeof(char)`. Also `sizeof(char)` is always 1 so no need for it at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line has a problem:

```
pNew = (nNameStruct*) malloc(sizeof(nNameStruct*));
```

It should be sizeof(nNameStruct). When the struct contains a single pointer the size of nNameStruct* and nNameStruct may be the same, when there are two pointers in the struct you need to allocate more.